deploying react/.net site to azure using vite to build and github actions to run yaml - no error, just doesn't deploy. .scm does show files
i have been trying to deploy this react/.net.  it uses vite to build.  i am using github actions to run the yaml.  my yaml looks like this so far:    what IS working is that i go to http://mysitename-xxxxxxx.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net’   and i see all the files minified or whatever…   but when I go to the site without that .scm, i get NO CONTENT - standard message from azure.    here’s the yaml.
name: Build and deploy full-stack app to Azure Web App
on:
 push:
   branches:
     - master
 workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
 build:
   runs-on: windows-latest
   env:
     CI: false
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     - name: Set up .NET Core
       uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
       with:
         dotnet-version: ‘7.0.x’
     - name: Install dotnet-ef tool
       run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.*
     - name: Add .NET tools to PATH
       run: echo “${HOME}/.dotnet/tools” >> $GITHUB_PATH
     - name: Restore .NET dependencies
       run: dotnet restore CharityProject.sln
     - name: Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package
       run: dotnet add CharityProject.Web/CharityProject.Web.csproj package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 7.0.0
     - name: Set up Node.js
       uses: actions/setup-node@v2
       with:
         node-version: ‘18.x’
     - name: Install frontend dependencies
       run: |
         cd CharityProject.Web/ClientApp
         npm install
     - name: Build frontend
       run: |
         cd CharityProject.Web/ClientApp
         npm run build
     - name: Wait for build to complete
       run: sleep 10
     - name: Verify frontend build output
       run: |
         Write-Host “Listing dist folder contents”
         Get-ChildItem -Path CharityProject.Web/ClientApp/dist
     - name: Verify dist folder contents
       run: |
         Write-Host “Listing dist folder contents”
         Get-ChildItem -Path CharityProject.Web/ClientApp/dist
     - name: Copy frontend build to wwwroot
       run: |
         mkdir -p CharityProject.Web/wwwroot
         cp -r CharityProject.Web/ClientApp/dist/* CharityProject.Web/wwwroot/
       shell: bash
     - name: Verify wwwroot contents
       run: |
         Write-Host “Listing wwwroot folder contents”
         Get-ChildItem -Path CharityProject.Web/wwwroot
     - name: Build with dotnet
       run: dotnet build CharityProject.sln --configuration Release
     - name: Publish Web Project
       run: dotnet publish CharityProject.Web/CharityProject.Web.csproj -c Release -o myapp
     - name: Verify myapp contents
       run: |
         Write-Host “Listing myapp folder contents”
         Get-ChildItem -Path myapp
     - name: Verify myapp/wwwroot contents
       run: |
         Write-Host “Listing myapp/wwwroot folder contents”
         if (Test-Path -Path myapp/wwwroot) {
         Get-ChildItem -Path myapp/wwwroot
           } else {
         Write-Host “myapp/wwwroot directory does not exist.”
         }
         exit 0
     - name: Apply database migrations
       run: dotnet ef database update --project CharityProject.Data/CharityProject.Data.csproj --startup-project CharityProject.Web/CharityProject.Web.csproj
       env:
         ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING }}
     - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
       uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
       with:
         name: .net-app
         path: myapp
 deploy:
   runs-on: windows-latest
   needs: build
   environment:
     name: ‘Production’
     url: ‘http://mysitename-xxxxxxx.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net’
   steps:
     - name: Download artifact from build job
       uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
       with:
         name: .net-app
     - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
       id: deploy-to-webapp
       uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
       with:
         app-name:‘myappservicename’
         slot-name: ‘Production’
         publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
         package: . 

and here's the vite.config.js.  

 import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5091',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '/api')
      },
      '/uploads': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5091',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/uploads/, '/uploads'),
      },
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist', // Specify the output directory for the build
    rollupOptions: {
      // Customize rollup options if necessary
    },
  },
});

and here's the package.json that is inside the clientapp:
{
    "name": "clientapp",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.1",
        "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.172",
        "@mui/material": "^5.16.1",
        "axios": "^1.6.8",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-confirm": "^0.3.0-7",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
        "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
        "vite": "^5.2.0"
    }
}.  

and here is program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.IO;

namespace CharityProject.Web;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var CookieScheme = "CharityProjectScheme";

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000","https://mysite-xxxxx.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/","https://mysite-xxxxxx.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net")
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/admin/loginAdmin";
            });
        builder.Services.AddSession();

        var app = builder.Build();

        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Middleware order is important
        //app.UseStaticFiles();

          // Serve static files from ClientApp/dist
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp", "dist")),
                RequestPath = ""
            });
        
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin"); // Use the specific CORS policy

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSession();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

        app.Run();
    }
}

